# How to split in between a string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, split

I have the following string in a text file:

```
^b^B
```

I'm trying to split this into two variables. My current code is using `explode()` but it does not work as I want it to:

```
$num1 = '^b';
$num2 = '^B';
```

How can I accomplish this using PHP?

THIS IS MY CODE

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['refresh'])) {
exec('/var/www/www.rfteste.com/htdocs/estado.sh');
}
if(isset($_POST['on'])) {
exec('/var/www/www.rfteste.com/htdocs/on.sh');
}
if(isset($_POST['off'])) {
exec('/var/www/www.rfteste.com/htdocs/off.sh');
}
echo "<H3>CONTROL PANEL</H3>";
$str = file_get_contents("/var/www/www.rfteste.com/htdocs/refresh.txt");
$vals = explode("^", $str);
$num1 = "^".$vals[0];
$num2 = "^".$vals[1];
$onoff= "^A";
if($num2 == $onoff)
echo "<b>on</b>";
else
echo "<b>off</b>";
?>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
<p>
<center><input type="submit" value="on" name="on""';" /></center>
<center><input type="submit" value="off" name="off""';" /></center>
<center><input type="submit" value="refresh" name="refresh""';" /></center>
```

Comment: @Andrea he did but i don't why after edited his tried went away by him or by other user

Comment: @Naeem: It was removed by the OP itself. See the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/22257093/7) for more details

Comment: I find this question a little Unclear.  The coding attempt does nothing to improve this.  Are the letter significant or are the carets significant or are both significant.  How will these input values vary?  Are they always 4 characters?  Can you just split the string in half? or is there additional logic to respect?

Comment: What are you getting in $num1 and $num2 in this code?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split) with a lookaround assertion:

```
list($num1, $num2) = preg_split('/(?<=\^b)/', $str);
```

**Autopsy:**

- `/` - starting delimiter
- `(?<=` - start of positive lookbehind (meaning "if preceded by")

  - `\^b` - match literal characters `^b`
- `)` - end of positive lookbehind
- `/` - ending delimiter

**Visualization:**

[image]

In plain english, it means: split on places where it's preceded by a `^b` and assign the array values to the variables `$num1` and `$num2` using the [`list`](http://php.net/list) construct.

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/115772)

Answer (score 1):

Use [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/preg_match_all):

```
<?php
$str = '^b^B';
preg_match_all('/(\^.)/', $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Pull all of the contents of file, myfile.txt, into variable, $str
$str = file_get_contents("myfile.txt");

#split up the data in $str, at every instance of '^'. 
$vals = explode("^", $str);
#now $vals is an array of strings

#concatenate the "^" back into the strings as they were removed by explode.
$num1 = "^".$vals[0];
$num2 = "^".$vals[1];
```

Comment: I feel like you didn't test your code. https://3v4l.org/HQojs