# I have the following string in a text file:

Tags: php

I have a code but is not working, I'm trying use explode but still not working.
My code have two strings:

```
^@^b = (on)
^A^b = (off)
```

I try to get only 2 characters from a .txt file in a variable like:

```
$on=^@
$off=^A
```

then I can use the result to verify the state of light using a dimmer.

**Code**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['estado'])) {
exec('/var/www/www.rfteste.com/htdocs/estado.sh');
}
if(isset($_POST['ligar'])) {
exec('/var/www/www.rfteste.com/htdocs/liga.sh');
}
if(isset($_POST['desligar'])) {
exec('/var/www/www.rfteste.com/htdocs/desliga.sh');
}
echo "<H3>CONTROL PANEL</H3>";
$str = file_get_contents("/var/www/www.rfteste.com/htdocs/estado.txt");
$vals = explode("^", $str); 
$num1 = "^".$vals[0];
$num2 = "^".$vals[1];
$onoff= "^A";
if($num2 == $onoff)
echo "<b>on</b>";
else
echo "<b>off</b>";
?>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
<p>
<center><input type="submit" value="Ligar" name="ligar""';" /></center>
<center><input type="submit" value="desligar" name="desligar""';" /></center>
<center><input type="submit" value="atualizar" name="estado""';" /></center>
```

Comment: What code do you have that isn't working?

Comment: Answers given in your [`other question`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22257093/) were rendered useless given by some rather high ranking `K` members. **Edit**: Oh, so *now* you decide to show *full* code.

Comment: `var_dump($vals)` will probably show you where you're going wrong.

Comment: `name="ligar""';"` ? and no closing `</form>` tag. Ya gotta love missing (*& extra*) parts.

Answer (score 0):

i think this can help you solve your problem

```
function checktext($text){
    if(preg_match("'@'", $text)){
        return 'on';
    }else{
        return 'off';
    }
}
echo checktext('^A^b');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [php substr()](http://www.php.net/substr)

```
if(substr($str, 0, 1) == "A")
{
echo "<b>on</b>";
} else {
echo "<b>off</b>";
}
```